# Probability index yolov2 darknet openCV3.4

Tags: opencv, classification

I'm refer to https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/dnn/yolo_object_detection.cpp

What is meant by line # 136?

```
const int probability_index = 5;
```

How do i modify the bounding box calculations of I were to just classify the image ( I'm interested in the object detection but just the image classification)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOLO models, at least `YoloV2voc` and `TinyYoloV2voc`, produce output matrices of shape `Nx(C+4)` where `N` is a number of detections, `C` is a number of classes (including background), `4` is a vector `[centerX, centerY, width, height]`. So classification confidences start from 5th element.

Comment: Thanks. I have 4 classes, and I get the 9x245 matrix.  Does it mean, the  5th element shows the probability of the background?  What if I want to classify the image  based on these matrix? How should I use this result?

Comment: Perhaps an every detection is a vector `[centerX, centerY, width, height, xxx, conf_class_1, conf_class_2, conf_class_3, conf_class_4]`. What actually on the position `xxx` I don't sure.

Comment: Thanks. One more question.  I'm getting width and height sometimes more than the height and the width of  actual image  that I  want to classify and not interested in a  specific  object detection. Why it is so?

Comment: Hello, can someone please add an answer to my last question?